# Can't replace syscall instruction with ptrace in Arm linux

Tags: c, linux, arm, system-calls, ptrace

I tried to change syscall behavior to remote process with `ptrace` in Arm linux while the process is access `write` syscall

ptrace.c

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <asm/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/user.h>


void main(int argc, char**argv){


    int pid = atoi (argv[1]);

    int retval;
    int i = 0 ; 


    if((retval = ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL ,NULL)) ==-1) {
        printf("error PTRACE_ATTACH \n");
    }

    wait(NULL);

    struct user_regs attack_regs;
    while(1)
    {
        if((retval = ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, NULL ,NULL)) ==-1) {
            printf("error PTRACE_SYSCALL \n");
        }
        wait(NULL);

        if((retval = ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, NULL ,&attack_regs)) ==-1) { 
            printf("error PTRACE_GETREGS \n");
            return;
        }
        printf("call : command = %lu , r0 = %lu , r1 = %lu , r2 = %lu \n",attack_regs.ARM_r7 , attack_regs.ARM_r0 , attack_regs.ARM_r1, attack_regs.ARM_r2);
        if(attack_regs.ARM_r7 ==4 ) //write syscall
        {

            i++;
            if(i % 3 ==0)
            {
                attack_regs.ARM_r2=2 ; //edit write count
                if((retval = ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, NULL ,&attack_regs)) ==-1) { 
                    printf("error PTRACE_SETREGS \n");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        if((retval = ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, NULL ,NULL)) ==-1) {
            printf("error PTRACE_SYSCALL \n");
        }
        wait(NULL);

        if((retval = ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, NULL ,&attack_regs)) ==-1) { 
            printf("error PTRACE_GETREGS \n");
            return;
        }



        printf("result : command = %lu , r0 = %lu , r1 = %lu , r2 = %lu \n",attack_regs.ARM_r7 , attack_regs.ARM_r0 , attack_regs.ARM_r1, attack_regs.ARM_r2);
    }

    if((retval = ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL ,NULL)) ==-1) {
            printf("error PTRACE_DETACH\n");
    }

}
```

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main ()
{
    char * bu ="123456789";
    int i = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        sleep(1);
        write(1,bu+(i%10),1);
        i++;
    }
}
```

test.c print each one sec. only 1 char (1..2...3..) .

When  I attach to test pid with ptrace , each 3 times of `write` syscall I change that it print 2 chars instead of 1 char (by edit r2 register `attack_regs.ARM_r2=2 ;` ), that working fine .

What I tried now is to edit the syscall number , that diffrent syscall will be called by edit `r7 register`, like `attack_regs.ARM_r7=0x18` (`getuid` syscall) or another , but that not work.

Even I see that `r7` is realy edit , the diffrent syscall not called.

Why is that ?

Comment: When you catch a syscall first time, it has already started. You cannot change this fact. It will continue and you will catch its exit. you cannot redirect it just by changing its number. You can do something like LD_PRELOAD or other tricks to replace write with something else in the executable.

Comment: @Serge this is not true in general, but indeed for older arm kernels. I would consider this a bug, which was fixed in newer kernels (>=3.16 I believe).

Comment: @Serge @Ctx  1) `LD_PRELOAD` not help me because I want  to do that for running process  2) So why I can edit register `r2` but can't edit register `r7` ?